# Why are these Images bigger then original size?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, image

I have multiple images that I pull from facebook. They are placed in a scroller. When you click on the image a `dialog` appears with the actual image (The images in the scroller are thumbnail size, what you get from a facebook query with `src_small`)

I cannot determine the size of the images before I get them. Some are huge and others very small. To account for this (so all images fit in the `dialog` and are a reasonable size) I tried this:

```
/*
 * Image in the dialog div
 */
 .DialogImagesBig
 {
     position: relative;
     width: 95%;
     top: 0px;
     left: 10px;
 }
 /*
  * Firefox only
  */
 @-moz-document url-prefix() 
 {
     /*
      * Edits images for FF
      */
     .DialogImagesBig
     {
         height: 95% !important;
         width: 95% !important;
         position: relative;
         top: 0px;
         left: 10px;
     }
}
```

But it actually makes some images bigger then they are (Big images are smaller, but small images are bigger and pixelated). Why is that? How would I fix this so that all images fit in the `dialog` and are not pixelated?

**Edit** I have been told that I need to use Javascript (or Jquery?) to get this done. How would I go about doing that?

Comment: you are resizing using CSS, it will make the image "fit", it isn't a processor that will only make images smaller, it makes them all 95%. which means it enlarges some. You'll need Javascript to do what you are trying.

Comment: Because setting the `width` in FF will make the image off, and setting the `height` in chrome and everything else will make the image off

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the image width/height by doing this:

```
var img = new Image();
img.src = _image_src_

img.width // returns width
img.height // returns height

img // returns <img src="_image_src_" />
```

You can compare those values with the width/height of your dialog and do all the resizing you need, i hope this can help.

Example:

```
if (img.width > 100) 
  img.width = 100

$("#image_container").html(img)
```

Comment: Yup I just found another article like that. I think this is the only way that will work for what I want to do

Answer (score 2):

A width/height of `95%` means 95% of the *parent element's width/height*, not 95% of the image's original size.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this sort of thing:

```
h = $('#theimage').height();
w = $('#theimage').width();

if(h > 400 && w < 500) {
    $('#theimage').height(400);
    $('#theimage').width = w / (h / 400);
}
...
...
```

same for other comparisons, to shrink it down appropriately.  I think the math is right there...